# Show file content with shell variables loaded

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know `sed` can help to replace strings in file.

Can I show file content with shell variables loaded without `sed` ?

For my case, I have a file with variables as `/tmp/my_vars` , sample :

```
VAR_DIR="/etc/my_conf"
VAR_FILE_A="fileA"
```

Prepared template as `/tmp/my_template` , sample :

```
File A is located in $VAR_DIR/$VAR_FILE_A .
```

I have a bash script executed this ( for loading variables ) :

```
. /tmp/my_vars
```

I wonder if I can put a simple command in the script showing like this:

```
File A is located in /etc/my_conf/fileA .
```

Anyway, thanks for any help.

Comment: Under `VAR_FILE_A` add `echo "File A is located in ${VAR_DIR}/${VAR_FILE_A}"`

Comment: Depends on your definition of "simple". Bash does not do this out of the box.  A data file is not Bash code, and vice versa.  There are things you can do which as such are not very hard but the behavior you seem to be looking for is not as such a feature of Bash.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pure shell solution (not recommended)

```
. /tmp/my_vars
eval "echo $(cat /tmp/my_template)"
```

The problem with this approach is that it runs `eval` on whatever is in the file `/tmp/my_template`.  That can be [dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

#### awk solution (recommended)

awk is a good tool for this:

```
$ awk -F'[="]+' 'FNR==NR{a["[$]"$1]=$2;next} {for (i in a) gsub(i,a[i]);} 1' /tmp/my_vars /tmp/my_template
File A is located in /etc/my_conf/fileA .
```

#### How it works

This reads in `/tmp/my_vars` first, gathering all the substitution information.  It then reads in `/tmp/my_template` making substitutions one line at a time.

- `-F'[="]+'`

  This tells awk to use any combinations of `=` or `"` as the field separator
- `FNR==NR{ a[ "[$]" $1 ]=$2; next}`

  While we are on the first file, that is while `FNR==NR`, we add an entry to array `a` for each line with the first field as the key and the second as the value.

  To the beginning of the key string we add a dollar sign.  Because `$` is an active regex character, we place it inside square brackets, `[$]` so that it is treated as a regular character.
- `for (i in a) gsub(i,a[i])`

  For each key in `a`, this performs the substitutions.  Every place in the current line that the key, `i`, appears, it is replaced with the value `a[i]`.
- `1`

  This prints the lines.

## Formatted over multiple lines

For those who like their code spread over multiple lines:

```
awk -F'[="]+' '
FNR==NR{
    a["[$]"$1]=$2
    next
}

{
    for (i in a) gsub(i,a[i])
}

1
```

Comment: looks line noise either way

Comment: @JarrodRoberson What do you mean by that?  Is it that you don't like awk?  Or, what?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the process of loading `my_vars` to print out all the variables that were loaded from that file, you could add the following to the bottom of `my_vars`:

```
# Permit extended notation for parameter expansion
shopt -s extglob

# Step through the file, printing lines that look like variable assignments
while read line; do
  case "$line" in
    +([A-Z_])=*)
      var="${line%%=*}"
      eval "echo \"Variable '$var' is set to '\$$var'\""
      ;;
  esac
done < $BASH_SOURCE
```

This will simply dump your variables in the sourced file.  It does not assemble things into directory and filename as the example in your question specified.  That kind of assembly would be custom depending on the variables, and not in scope for a generic solution like this one.  In that case, you could add to your script:

```
echo "File A is located in ${VAR_DIR}/${VAR_FILE_A}"
```

along with similar lines for any other variables whose content you want to see when the file is loaded.